# asyncio across multiple long lived client connections

Tags: python, python-3.x, network-programming, python-asyncio

I am trying to write a simple application that connects to multiple rudimentary TCP servers with long lived connections where I send/receive data from each connection.  Basically receiving events from the server, sending commands back and receiving results from the commands.  Think of controlling a device, but i want to control **N** devices on a single thread.

I have a working non-async, non-blocking implementation, but the time.sleep() are killing the responsiveness or killing the CPU, and using `select` is so much cooler.

Given the below example, i want to connect to all three servers, and `await receive_message` on each one simultaneously.  Currently, it's blocked in the `connect`'s receive_message(), so I only get this output:

```
Connecting to 1
Sending password to 1
Waiting for message from 1
```

I'd like to get something similar to this, not exactly, but showing that the connections are all independently scheduled.

```
Connecting to 1
Connecting to 2
Connecting to 3
Sending password to 1
Sending password to 2
Sending password to 3
Waiting for message from 1
Waiting for message from 2
Waiting for message from 3
Connected to 1
Connected to 2
Connected to 3
Waiting for message from 1
Waiting for message from 2
Waiting for message from 3
```

Watered down version of what i'm trying.  No, the real server isn't this insecure.... this is just an example.

```py
import asyncio


class Connection:
    def __init__(self, name, host, port):
        self.name = name
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.reader, self.writer = None, None
        self.connected = False

    async def connect(self):
        print(f'Connecting to {self.name}')
        self.reader, self.writer = await asyncio.open_connection(self.host, self.port)
        await self.send_message('password')
        response = await self.receive_message()
        if response == 'SUCCESS':
            self.connected = True
            print(f'Connected to {self.name}')
        else:
            raise Exception('unsuccessful connection')
        print(f'Connected to {self.name}')

    async def send_message(self, message):
        print(f'Sending {message} to {self.name}')
        self.writer.write(f'{message}\n'.encode('utf-8'))

    async def receive_message(self):
        print(f'Waiting for message from {self.name}')
        return (await self.reader.readline()).decode('utf-8')


connections = (
    Connection(1, 'localhost', 21114),
    Connection(2, 'localhost', 21115),
    Connection(3, 'localhost', 21116)
)


async def run():
    for connection in connections:
        await connection.connect()
    # how to receive messages from each connection as they are received
    for connection in connections:
        await connection.receive_message()

asyncio.run(run())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `await` in the `for` loop is effectively serializing your connections. In asyncio parallelism happens at the level of *task*, so if you want the connections to run in parallel, you need to spawn several tasks (or use a function that will do it for you, such as `asyncio.gather`). For example:

```py
async def handle_connection(conn):
    await conn.connect()
    await conn.receive_message()
    # ...

async def run():
    tasks = []
    for conn in connections:
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(handle_connection(conn)))
    # wait until all the tasks finish
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```